# Find $d/dx f(x)$ given that $d/dx [f(e^x )] = x$

Tags: calculus, functions

I was given this question as part of some coursework, and I came to an answer by:
Integrating to get $f(e^x) = 0.5*x^2 (+c)$;
Replacing $x$ with $\ln(x)$ to get $f(x) = 0.5*(\ln(x))^2 (+c)$;
Differentiating to get $d/dx f(x) = \ln(x)/x$.

However, a friend interpreted the question as saying that if $d/dx f(x) = g(x)$, then $g(e^x)= x$. This leads to $d/dx f(x) = g(x) = \ln(x)$. Which is correct, or is the question too vaguely stated for a correct answer to be determined? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend is incorrect, as the equation is $\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(e^x)\right) = x$ and not $\left(\frac{d}{dx} f\right)(e^x) = x$. The former means that you need to derive the function $x \mapsto f(e^x)$, while the latter means you plug $e^x$ into the derivative of $f$.

There is also a slightly simpler solution than yours. By the chain rule you have $f'(e^x) e^x = x$, which means $f'(x) = f'(e^{\ln(x)}) = \ln(x) e^{-\ln(x)} = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$.